# displaying question and answers in vertical format

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want to display questions and answers centered on the screen in vertical format. I also need to display a button right next to the question that shows more information about that question. I am trying to do this:

```
Which Grade are you in?
    Second
    Third
    Fourth
    Fifth
```

all the answers are the radio buttons and user can only select one answer. I can do this using bootstrap like so, but I am not sure how to display the question at the top and the radio button indented underneath the question.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">  <input type="radio" id="Second"  value="Second">
  <label for="huey">Second</label></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="radio" id="Third"  value="Third">
  <label for="huey">Third</label></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="radio" id="Fourth"  value="Fourth">
  <label for="huey">Fourth</label></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="radio" id="Fifth"  value="Fifth">
  <label for="huey">Fifth</label></li>

</ul>
```

I want to use either flexbox or bootstrap to display questions and answers. I have to display 40 questions with space in between each question.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean 'centered underneath the question'? Your example shows the list indented underneath the question but it is not centered in relation to the length of the question's text.

Comment: Yes, indented underneath the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you need something like this?

```js
let hintButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.toggleHint')
hintButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.onclick = function() { toggleHide(this.parentElement.parentElement) }
})

function toggleHide(quesContainer) {
  let hint = quesContainer.children[1]
  hint.classList.toggle('hide')
}
```

```css
.answer-options {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.extraInfo {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.question-container {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.question {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggleHint {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="question-container">
<div class="question"> What grade are you in? <button class="toggleHint btn btn-primary">Toggle Hint</button> </div>
<div class="extraInfo hide">Here is some extra info about this question.</div>
<ul class="answer-options">
  <li class="form-check">  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="second"  value="Second" name="answer-1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="second">Second</label></li>
  <li class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="third"  value="Third" name="answer-1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="third">Third</label></li>
  <li class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="fourth"  value="Fourth" name="answer-1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="fourth">Fourth</label></li>
  <li class="form-check"><input type="radio" id="fifth"  value="Fifth" name="answer-1" class="form-check-input">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="fifth">Fifth</label></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="question-container">
<div class="question"> Did you raed this properly? <button class="toggleHint btn btn-primary">Toggle Hint</button> </div>
<div class="extraInfo hide">Here is some extra info about this question.</div>
<ul class="answer-options">
  <li class="form-check">  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="yes"  value="Yes" name="answer-2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">Yes</label></li>
  <li class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="no"  value="No" name="answer-2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="no">No</label></li>
  <li class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="obviously"  value="Obviously" name="answer-2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="obviously">Obviously</label></li>
  <li class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="maybe"  value="Maybe" name="answer-2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="fifth">Maybe</label></li>
</ul>
</div>
```